# Populating a matrix of function evaluations in R without for-loop

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix

I'd like to generate a matrix whose values are evaluations of a function which has two arguments.

So far, the following does what I want, but I suspect that there is a nicer way to do this in R, without using the `for` loops.

```
x <- c(0.01, 0.1,1,10,100)
n <- length(x)
M <- matrix(NA, nrow=n, ncol=n)
for (i in 1:n){
 for (j in 1:n){
  M[i,j]<-x[i]^x[j]
 }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `outer` function:

```
> outer(x,x,"^")
          [,1]      [,2]  [,3]  [,4]   [,5]
[1,] 0.9549926 0.6309573 1e-02 1e-20 1e-200
[2,] 0.9772372 0.7943282 1e-01 1e-10 1e-100
[3,] 1.0000000 1.0000000 1e+00 1e+00  1e+00
[4,] 1.0232930 1.2589254 1e+01 1e+10 1e+100
[5,] 1.0471285 1.5848932 1e+02 1e+20 1e+200
> identical(M,outer(x,x,"^"))
[1] TRUE
```

You can use a function name or the quoted name of an operator. Note also I test that the answer from `outer` is the same as that from your loop. Always test!

Answer (score 2):

Use the `outer` function :

```
outer(x,x,"^")

          [,1]      [,2]  [,3]  [,4]   [,5]
[1,] 0.9549926 0.6309573 1e-02 1e-20 1e-200
[2,] 0.9772372 0.7943282 1e-01 1e-10 1e-100
[3,] 1.0000000 1.0000000 1e+00 1e+00  1e+00
[4,] 1.0232930 1.2589254 1e+01 1e+10 1e+100
[5,] 1.0471285 1.5848932 1e+02 1e+20 1e+200
```